# cannot find method copyTo error after creating new file in sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Would really appreciate your help here.

I'm creating a two step process where:
1. Create a new file named after a cell from the file to be copied from.
2. Copy the sheet to the newly created file.

I'm doing this because we will be creating unique files for several clients and I'd like to automate it.

Since I'm still new, I've been putting together code from various sources and modifying it to put what I want. However, this code creates a new file perfectly, but refuses to copy the content to the newly created file. I keep on getting a "cannot find method CopyTo error" and despite a ton of research and tweaking, I cannot get it to work. Help!?

```
function copy2() {

var folder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Dummy").next();
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0,1];
 var cellWithFileName = ss.getRange("A1");
 var name = cellWithFileName.getValue();
var file=SpreadsheetApp.create(name);
 var fileID = file.getId()
var copyFile=DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
 var destination = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID)
folder.addFile(copyFile);

DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(copyFile);

ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").copyTo(fileID);

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At `copyTo(destination)`, `destination` is not file ID. It's Spreadsheet. So how about the following modification?

#### From :

```
ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").copyTo(fileID);
```

#### To :

```
ss.getSheetByName("sheet1").copyTo(file);
```

#### Reference :

- [copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)

If this didn't work, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Comment: It worked like a charm! I feel so silly for missing something so small (insert frustration emoji here). THANKS! However, I have a follow up question based on something I noticed. The copyTo method copies everything. I ONLY want to copy values and formatting. Using the 'ss.getSheetByName("Thinning #1").copyTo(file,{formatOnly:true});' method gives a "Cannot find method copyTo" error. What am I missing?

Comment: @Sam I'm sorry. I couldn't understand about your current situation from the comment. Can you post it by including the detail information as a new question? By this, I and other users will be able to think of your issue.